# SQLSRV Error sqlsrv_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given and sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Im getting error message in running sqlsrv. Basically, I'm trying to make a pagination here but getting the error message:

> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trueensemble\search.php on line 67
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trueensemble\search.php on line 69

Below is the line 67 and 69

```
$getquery=sqlsrv_query("SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");

while($runrows=sqlsrv_fetch_array($getquery))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter for sqlsrv_query must be a connection, i.e.

`$getquery = sqlsrv_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");`

Comment: thanks, that removed the line 67 error, but still getting error message in Line 69, i edited my post hoping someone could see the error.

Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trueensemble\search.php on line 69

Comment: `$getquery` is false when an error occurs, and so causes line 69 to fail. Is the code for the sqlsrv_query valid SQL? Try something like `echo "SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page";` to verify your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I did echoed it and now I got this.

SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE TAGS LIKE '%%' LIMIT 0, 1


.. I also tried generating error reporting and I got this

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. ) )

Now, I'm not sure if the error comes from $construct or LIMIT..

Comment: You cannot use LIMIT in MSSQL. Try using TOP instead, i.e. `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [dbo].[table]`. Also, see this blog post for another method that lets you specify a start and count, just like MySQL's LIMIT: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserver/archive/2006/10/25/limit-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Also, if you are using MSSQL 2012 or higher, you could rewrite your SQL statement to this: `$getquery = sqlsrv_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct OFFSET $start ROWS FETCH NEXT $per_page ROWS ONLY");`

Comment: Thank you! That sorts out the 2 errors, but getting new error messages though not related to this one.